# What song is Kyoko dancing to in Puella Magi / Mahou Shoujo Madoka Magica?

Tags: madoka-magica, music

I've just been re-watching Puella Magi Madoka Magica / Mahou Shoujo Madoka Magica (episodes, movie, doesn't change this situation). I noticed a song that sounded quite nice, that Kyoko was dancing to (playing Dance Dance Revolution, if you're happy to go by that name) in the 6th episode, or at 1:20:25 roughly, during the first movie. I'd like to make it clear that I am referring to the **first song** she dances to, **not the second**. I am well aware that the second song is *Connect* by *ClariS*.

The scene can be found at [this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKwjb7Lyc9c). It starts right near the beginning. What is this song / tune? Does anyone know the name, artist, or what it is from, if it is known outside of Madoka Magica?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: well, it's actually Connect -Game Installation- It's on track 13 on Mahou Shoujo Madoka Magica Special CD 6. But I couldn't find any more detail about it

Comment: Ah, this is a feeling I don't like. You're right, it actually is all part of the same song - I was mislead, believing it she was dancing to multiple. Will you make an official answer, or should I deal with this another way? (Also, thanks!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's part of the song Connect. You can say it's a remix version. The title is Connect -Game Installation-

It's from [Mahou Shoujo Madoka Magica Special CD 6 (track #13)](http://www.jpmusic.info/2011/09/mahou-shoujo-madoka-magica-ost-3.html).

Mahou Shoujo Madoka Magica has total 6 Bonus CD. From what I could see, the artist is still ClariS. (I actually has all the bonus CD)