# Do the Madoka OST CDs have sensible musical notation printed on them?

Tags: music, madoka-magica

Do these Madoka original soundtrack disks have some comprehensible melodies printed on them or are they just random notation signs? If it is possible, I'd like to hear what is written on them.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks pretty random to me. I can't quite figure out what the rhythms are supposed to be (since I can't figure out what the standard musical notation that corresponds to some of the symbols is supposed to be), but at minimum, the pitch sequences don't seem to resemble anything on the Madoka soundtrack.

Comment: i see [Repeat signs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musical_symbols#Repetition_and_codas) every 90 degrees of the disk, it seems to indicate that the lines are an infinite loop, the only thing i can think of in the soundtrack which one could loop endlessly is [Connect ~Game Instrumental/Installation~](http://wiki.puella-magi.net/Soundtrack#OST_Volume_3) though this is on my original basis that the track was the installation music for the PSP game (when actually it's the music [Kyoko dances to](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/14427/1587))

Answer (score 1):

It might be readable if there was some difference between the minims and crotchets and quavers, but due to the lack of time signature and bar lines, I would say that the design on these discs is just that, a design. Also, as senshin commented, it doesn't seem to resemble anything from the Madoka soundtrack anyway.